# D3, VueJS, SVG not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to experiment with visualizing some data on vue with d3js. I am following this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuecoTcqmVE at 1:39 in the video. for some reason my code is crashing my vue app. I am wondering what's wrong with this code? I am not importing some necessary tools? I am running vue 2 with d3 dependencies

```
    <template>
      <!-- svg -->
      <div>
        <svg
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          @click="addPoint"
          @contextmenu.prevent
          points=" []"
        >
          <!-- circles -->
          <circle
            v-for="(item, index) in points"
            :key="index"
            r="10"
            :cx="item.x"
            :cy="item.y"
          ></circle>
          <!-- path -->
          <path
            fill="transparent"
            stroke="dark"
            stroke-width="1"
            :d="lineGenerator(points)"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import * as d3 from "d3"
    
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          points: [{ x: 200, y: 500 }]
        },
      },
    },
      methods: {
        /**@Param {MouseEvent} ev */
        addPoint(ev) {
          Const = {
          layerX:x,
          layerY:y
          } = ev
        this.points.push ({
          x,
          y
        }),
        },
        computed: {
          return d3.line() 
           .x(item => item.x),
           .y(item => item.y)
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: "crashing my vue app" - what's the error

Comment: You have a number of issues. For example `Const = { ...` and you have a computed object with a return statement. This is not valid. I would return to your video and follow the instructions more carefully. In the video, check if they have a link to a repository and try following along from there.